# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get scrapy to follow links in the product section of a website I am scraping.  The problem is the links do not include the base url in the html and I cannot figure out how to get scrapy to follow them in my yield method.

I saw that you can use something called urljoin but cannot seem to get it working.
I also tried creating a variable named baseurl and trying to add baseurl + product but neither worked.

My code looks like this:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myscraper"
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.ca/product-search?s=true&=964%2C965'] 

def parse(self, response):
    for product in response.css("ol.unitList > li.unit > div.unit-title-wrapper > div.unit-title > a::attr('href')"):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=product.get(), callback=self.parseInnerPage)

def parseInnerPage(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```

Before adding the yield section I was able to print all of the urls in the product section, the results looked like this:

```
/product/product-1-url
/product/product-2-url
/product/product-3-url
/product/product-4-url
/product/product-5-url
/product/product-6-url
...
```

But when I add the yield method I get

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: /product/product-1-url
```

I think it's important to mention that example.ca does not have the product page on the homepage.  I just need example.ca added to the beginning of the results so I can follow them.

Comment: What is the actual url you are working with?

Comment: You propably forgot to add the `http` or `https` to your url. Oh, even the domain was missing.

Comment: No it was an absolute url issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT 4 got it figured.  Solution:

```
    import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myscraper"
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.ca/product-search?s=true&=964%2C965'] 

def parse(self, response):
    for product in response.css("ol.unitList > li.unit > div.unit-title-wrapper > div.unit-title > a::attr('href')"):
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(product.get())
            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url, callback=self.parseInnerPage)

def parseInnerPage(self, response):
    print(response.text)
```